# persistence-unit, different hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class property

Tags: jboss, glassfish, weblogic, persistence.xml

I have Java EE application, and my EJB module have `persistence.xml`.

I deploy my app on 3 app servers: JBoss, GlassFish and WebLogic, and every server needs own `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class` property.
WL needs

```
<property name="transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup" />
```

JBoss needs

```
<property name="transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
```

Glass fish

```
<property name="transaction.manager_lookup_class"    
value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is use

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
```

instead of

```
<property name="transaction.manager_lookup_class"
```